# How to vertically align text and image above a JRadioButton?

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jradiobutton

Is it possible to align both the text and image above the `JRadioButton` icon?

**Edit -**
Well, apparently setting the icon in the constructor actually replaces the default `JRadioButton` icon, which I wasn't expecting. Looks like I may have to use two separate components and throw them into the same container.

Comment: The UI delegate uses the icon. Would a `ButtonGroup` of `JToggleButton` with custom icon be an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will set the text above the JRadioButton:

```
radiobutton.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
radiobutton.setVerticalTextPosition(JRadioButton.TOP);
```

And yes, using the setIcon method replaces the JRadioButton icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
JRadioButton radioB = new JRasioButton (...);

radioB.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
```