# how can I define label position of a jRadioButton on Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, label, jradiobutton

I'd like to define label position of jRadioButtons on a buttonGroup on Netbeans so the label would be positioned under its radioButton. Can it be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically align text and image above a JRadioButton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669735/how-to-vertically-align-text-and-image-above-a-jradiobutton)

Comment: @ChrisCooney, actually it is a coding issue, but thanks for your insight.

Comment: @MrD, Yes. Got it done already! Thanks!

Comment: @trashgod, It is indeed a duplicate. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `JRadioButton#setText()` with `setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM)`.

```
JRadioButton jrb = new JRadioButton();
jrb.setText("Label");
jrb.setVerticalTextPosition(JRadioButton.BOTTOM);
jrb.setHorizontalTextPosition(JRadioButton.CENTER);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to use both `r.setVerticalTextPosition(JRadioButton.BOTTOM);` and
`r.setHorizontalTextPosition(JRadioButton.CENTER);` together. Otherwise, it will not work

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PersonFrame extends JFrame
{
    public PersonFrame()
    {
        JRadioButton r = new JRadioButton();
r.setText("Text");
r.setVerticalTextPosition(JRadioButton.BOTTOM);
r.setHorizontalTextPosition(JRadioButton.CENTER);

        JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
        testPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        testPanel.add(r);

        this.add(testPanel);
        this.setSize(100,100);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PersonFrame();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/), but see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @trashgod: SwingUtilities? Yes, I agree. :) I didn't thought of it, because I answered while doing my uni project. :) Thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: Right, `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. It's unlikely to manifest in this example, but it may be worth an edit if you reformat.

Comment: @trashgod: Sure. I will do the edit now. Thanks for pointing out that issue :)